# aws-sdk s3.getObject() size limit

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs, sharp

I am trying to process a 5GB tif file using sharp in a lambda function
but the s3.getObject() request fails with the following error:

```
{
  "errorType": "RangeError",
  "errorMessage": "The value \"5479395327\" is invalid for option \"size\"",
  "trace": [
    "RangeError [ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE]: The value \"5479395327\" is invalid for option \"size\"",
    "    at Function.alloc (buffer.js:370:3)",
    "    at Object.alloc (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:136:28)",
    "    at Object.concat (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/util.js:175:28)",
    "    at Request.HTTP_DONE (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:424:36)",
    "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
    "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
    "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)",
    "    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:334:26)",
    "    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)",
    "    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)"
  ]
}
```

code:

```
const getObjectRequest: GetObjectRequest = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: filename
};
const s3File = await s3.getObject(getObjectRequest).promise();
```

I've set the memory of the lambda function to 10240MB and timeout to 15 minutes (max).

Is there any other way to load the image into sharp?

Comment: Is this a ranged get? What are your parameters in the GetObject request?

Comment: @jarmod i've added my request. It contains only the bucket and the filename

Comment: You may be hitting some heap allocation limit with your runtime and you might have to perform multiple ranged gets, or simply stream the S3 content.

Comment: It seems that object size is exceeding buffer size. You would need to use multipart download. There are links related to this error and how to implement the fix:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1523
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2916